# Fast folder search within directory [Python]

Tags: python, performance, recursion, search, directory

Situation: A lot of files and folders into the main directory, very old work computers, old python 2.something(Software bound so nothing to be done for now), all the data is on a network drive.

I have a variable which contains the folder name it is supposed to find, there are like 2-4 of these withing each project. For ShotName = "DVX_010_400_BG_V001"

Expected output:

```
C:\Users\Dame\Desktop\NUKESTUFF\TPN\FilmLance\DVX\3dcomp\DVX_010_400_BG_V001

C:\Users\Dame\Desktop\NUKESTUFF\TPN\FilmLance\DVX\input\DVX_010_400_BG_V001

C:\Users\Dame\Desktop\NUKESTUFF\TPN\FilmLance\DVX\render\DVX_010_400_BG_V001
```

Goal: to find the folders that have the same name as the ShotName variable and return their path

Broblem: Current code is too slow and it hangs.

in my desktop env, the main folder is on dekstop (fast NVME ssd), the fastest processor, modern python so it's fast, like 2 seconds. My best code:

```
import os

ShotName = "DVX_010_400_BG_V001"
head_dir= "C:\\Users\\Dame\\Desktop\\NUKESTUFF\\TPN\\"


def dir_list_folder(head_dir, ShotName):
    """Return a list of the full paths of the subdirectories
    under directory 'head_dir' named 'ShotName'"""
    dirList = []
    for fn in os.listdir(head_dir):
        dirfile = os.path.join(head_dir, fn)
        if os.path.isdir(dirfile):
            print (dirfile)
            if fn.upper() == ShotName.upper():
                dirList.append(dirfile)
            else:
                dirList += dir_list_folder(dirfile, ShotName)


    return dirList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in dir_list_folder(head_dir, ShotName):
        # print (item)

        if "render" in item :
            ProjectPath = item.split("\\")[:-2]
            ProjectPath = "/".join(ProjectPath)
            print (f"ProjectPath = {ProjectPath}")
```

Comment: `os.walk` might be a bit faster; certainly easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried os.walk? You can use os.walk as so:

```
def FindFolder(Path, WantedFolder):
    corresponding = []
    for root, _, _ in os.walk(Path):
        
        if root.split("\\")[-1] == WantedFolder:
            corresponding.append(root)

    return corresponding
```

You will probably have to play with the split depending of the architecture of you system. This solution shoud be pretty efficient for odl systems.